# Drop down menu using jQuery animate lineHeight

Tags: jquery, css, menu, jquery-animate, contextmenu

The idea is to make a dropdown menu whereat first all the menu-items are stacked on top, and on hover they would animate down.

I did this by making the line-height 0. And on hover animate the lineHeight to 35px.

The problem is that this also moves the first line down, this will sometimes locate the mouse outside of the text and make it jump up again.

I tried leaving the first item out of the animation, but this results in a overlap.

Also after moving in and out a few times, I stops working for a second, I can't really find out why.

Does anyone have a solution?

My Javascript and jQuery skills are limited, so I try to be creative with the stuff that I know.

First try

HTML

```
<h2>
    <a>project one                <br></a>
    <a>number two                 <br></a>
    <a>this would be project three<br></a>
    <a>and number four            <br></a>
</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    left:10px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("h2").hover(function () {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        lineHeight: '35px'
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        lineHeight: '0px'
    });
});
```

Second

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<h2>
    <a>project one<br/>                                         </a>
    <span id="anim">
    <a>number two<br/>                                 </a>
    <a>this would be project three<br/>   </a>
    <a>and number four<br>                                     </a>
    </span>
</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("h2").hover(function () {
    $("#anim").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        lineHeight: '35px'
    });
}, function () {
    $("#anim").animate({
        lineHeight: '0px'
    });
});
```

Here also a jsfiddle:

- First try: http://jsfiddle.net/q85w4b2L/1/
- Second try: http://jsfiddle.net/zwxwLzp8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with animating the max-height rather than the line-height.  Also I would change your html structure as h2 should be used for titles - not a list of links.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul").hover(function () {
        $(this).children('li').animate({'max-height': 100}) // make the 100 larger than the tallest li
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('li').animate({'max-height': 0})
    });

});
```

```css
ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:10px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:400;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}

li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:visible;
    max-height:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a>project one</a></li>
            <li><a>number two</a></li>
            <li><a>this would be project three</a></li>
            <li><a>and number four</a></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works, the only thing it does not do is show all the items on top of eachother. Maybe i didn't formulate it will in my question. So the menu items are not supposed to be hidden while folded, they are just supposed to sit on top of eachother.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery already has a built-in method for doing animations like this, and it's aptly named .slideToggle(). Consider the following code...

HTML:

```
<h2>Hover Over Me</h2>
<nav>
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <a>Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    display:block;
    font-size:24px;}

nav {
    display:none;}

nav a {
    display:block;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('h2').hover(function(){

    $('nav').slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: I tried the slideToggle, but it hides all the menu items when they are folded in, i want to to sit on top of eachother while all being visible. Like a did in my the example.